# how to replace the forward slash to backslash and forward slash using javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to replace the "/" into "\/" using javascript.

for example:

```
http://www.freeformatter.com/javascript-escape.html
```

to

```
http:\/\/www.freeformatter.com\/javascript-escape.html
```

Comment: In what context are you using this? Are you trying to manually escape JavaScript strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use replace:

```
"http:/www.freeformatter.com/javascript-escape.html".replace(/\//g, "\\/");
```

If you have the string in a variable:

```
var url = "http:/www.freeformatter.com/javascript-escape.html";
url.replace(/\//g, "\\/");
```

Comment: right now, this outputs "http:\\/www.freeformatter.com\\/javascript-escape.html" instead of  "http:\/\/www.freeformatter.com\/javascript-escape.html". What i need to get "http:\/\/www.freeformatter.com\/javascript-escape.html".

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
str.replace(/\//g, "\\/");
```

where `str` is the variable that holds the string value.

Demo: http://jsbin.com/zijaqo/1/edit?js,console

Answer (score 0):

You could use str.replace() and a Regular expression object here. Basically you just need to escape the escape character in your replacement string.

```
str = str.replace(new RegExp('/','g'),"\\/");
```

Comment: Consider expanding your answer to explain to the asker why this achieves the desired result, possibly linking to documentation. As is, this is only marginally useful.